# Is there any substance that's a 0-0-0 on the NFPA diamond?

Tags: safety

Is there any substance that's a 0-0-0 on the NFPA diamond? Basically a perfectly safe chemical.

Comment: Since I'm closing this, I guess I should offer some kind of explanation. Essentially, it comes down to the fact that we do not need an exhaustive enumeration of every harmless chemical known to man. Furthermore, nobody can claim that there aren't enough answers already. Thus, I don't see any reason why this needs to be kept open.

Comment: Not sure how this questioned could be more focused.  It is a well-defined YES/NO question and the answer is clearly YES.  Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 12):

[**Water**](http://www.sciencelab.com/msds.php?msdsId=9927321)!

[image: Water MSDS]

---

You can find plenty of others if you perform [this search on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=%22NFPA-H+%3D+0%22+%22NFPA-F+%3D+0%22+%22NFPA-R+%3D+0%22&title=Special%3ASearch) (but then, go check the MSDS for the individual compounds before doing anything serious with them).

Comment: Wow, that was really obvious. I feel dumb.

Comment: I think this does not hold for all "types" of water. Imagine what pure water could to the the osmotic pressure in your cells. I don't know for sure, but I wouldn't drink a liter of distilled/deionized water.

Comment: A liter in your stomach would probably be ok, a liter in your lungs would cause trouble.

Comment: Any source on that?

Comment: @jori a Litre of distilled water would be far less troublesome than 10 litres of standard tap water. The difference in osmotic pressure from being deionised is small and not a notable hazard.

Comment: Since water can actually put fires out, maybe it should get a -1 red rating.

Comment: @JuanPerez if even possible

Answer (score 1):

[Sodium chloride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_chloride). Has a 0-0-0 rating with no special hazards.

Answer (score 1):

Compressed nitrogen and oxygen gases are rated 0-0-0, but it must be understood:

- Any relatively inert gas such as nitrogen could still suffocate you. Presumably the 0 rating is meant to interpret a base level of risk, **not zero**, as distinct from a higher level.
- Oxygen, of course, is listed as an oxidizer on the bottom of the diamond (special hazards).

Answer (score -1):

Also [Calcium carbonate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_carbonate). Same thing as sodium chloride- 0-0-0 with no special hazards.